Severity of the water damage
I recently purchased a 100 year old home. I discovered some water damage that was missed during the inspection. I've identified that the problem is that the gutters are clogged which caused a water breach and caused the roof to be come visibly molded. Luckily it appears to be only in that corner.
Inside, the drywall in that are was completely ruined and required no pressure to reach the stud. My main concern is how do I determine how much water damage the stud and/or header received? I did the old pocky test with a screwdriver. While the surface was soft and some would came off, it appeared to remain strong and sturdy but what do I know.
How much of the affected wall should I open up to assess the extent of the damage?


You keep going until you don't find any more damage or significant moisture. Once you do that, you dry things out thoroughly with fans, heat, and dehumidification as appropriate for your weather.
Then, if the lumber is still solid, it's probably not a concern. It takes substantial rot to compromise overall structural integrity. I can't be more specific than that from what we know here.
FYI, clogged gutters don't cause a roof leak. The roof should handle water flow without gutters. That mountain of tar is not an effective strategy. You'll want to address that as soon as you're able to install flashing and water barrier as appropriate.

That tar might make the leak worse by trapping water behind the shingles.  Yikes.
